# What is apple equivalent for Google Play Private Channel?

Tags: ios

Google has Google Play Private Channel to publish private apps.
Is there any apple equivalent for Google Play Private Channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can enroll for **Enterprise developer account**, it is same as Google Private channel

For more details visit this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html)